# Knp_Snappy, wkhtmltopdf built against patched qt - Ubuntu

Tags: symfony, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I use knp_snappy to generate pdf with symfony2.

It's working well but I need to add footer/header.
When I try to, wkhtmltopdf says that my version of qt doesn't have the wkhtmltopdf patches.

Is there's a way to patch qt without having to uninstall/reinstall wkhtmltopdf (The system is already used by clients, so it must keep working) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I'm unsure what you mean by 'qt', but you can specify where snappy looks for the wkhtmltopdf binary (as it says in its [documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle#configuration)) which enables you to choose to use whatever version you like.

In your config.yml file:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf #"\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\"" for Windows users
        options:    []
```

Comment: You're right, I just installed the binaries from the version I needed and you can switch from the file. It's working as expected,  thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've tried numerous `wkhtmltopdf` versions and I came to the conclusion that the package [h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64](https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64) works best.

```
composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
```

After that, you'll need to configure knp_snappy to use the newly installed binary:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     %kernel.root_dir%/../bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
        options:    []
```

Note that I've only tested this on Debian/Ubuntu.